# How do I "lock" my Linux box for few hours?

Tags: cron, login, pam

Since I over-use my computer, I would like to block it for few hours, for example every day from 23 to 7, so that I cannot use it in that time frame.

Currently, I am using `crontab` to suspend/shutdown the computer when it comes the time, and I do that every minute, so that - in general - if I try to log-in or turn on the computer, I have only few seconds before it is suspended again. The issue is that those few seconds are enough to change crontab and lock the mechanism.

So, I thought about blocking the login process completely (even for root!) in those hours, so that nobody could access the computer in any way, from 23 to 7. If I wanted to disable this behavior, I had to do it beforehand.

So, how can I configure my Linux box so that, for few hours, nobody can login? Should I use PAM? If yes, how?

Note: I would like to prevent logging in both with GDM and shell.

Comment: Just as a suggestion...maybe you should improve your discipline on going to sleep?  Or put the computer in a different room from the one you sleep in?  This is an interesting question from a *technical* standpoint, but I don't think you're solving the self-discipline issue at the right "layer" of the stack.  ;)

Comment: You are right, but I don't know how to patch my discipline :) Suggestions on how to change the right "layer" are welcome as well! (btw computer is not in the same room)

Comment: PAM allows to inhibit logins at arbitrary times, see `pam_time(8)` and `time.conf(5)`.

Comment: Put the power supply on a wall timer. Then put a piece of furniture in front of the socket to make it harder to defeat yourself.

Comment: Here's another attempt to solve at a technical level a problem that lies somewhere else. Such solutions are doomed to failure.

Comment: I regret I wrote my personal reasons behind the question.

Comment: By the way http://nedroid.com/comics/2010-05-05-beartato-willpower.gif

Comment: Maybe it's enough to cut the internet connection? Many routers have settings to disable connections depending on time. Set this up and tell someone else to change your router password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to disable the mouse and keyboard (assuming a system with USB input devices):

```
00 23 * * * rmmod usbhid
00  7 * * * modprobe usbhid
```

This won't prevent you from turning the system off and on again, which would re-enable the keyboard and mouse... You could play with blacklisting the module if you want to prevent that, but you'd probably need to rebuild your initramfs every time (`usbhid` needs to be loaded very early during the boot, since you want a working keyboard to fix things when the system can't boot).

If `usbhid` is built into the kernel on your system (*e.g.* Fedora), you can still achieve the same effect by unbinding all HID devices; the hard part then is re-binding them at 7am — you'll need to store somewhere the drivers from which they were unbound (unless there's a way of re-enumerating them). To unbind all devices:

```
for device in /sys/bus/hid/devices/*; do
    echo ${device##*/} > ${device}/driver/unbind
done
```

(with appropriate error checking of course). To re-bind, you need to remember what driver the `${device}/driver` pointed at, and `echo` the device identifier to `bind` in the driver's directory.

Comment: This is very nice, thanks! :) I definitely will not turn off the computer for that, it is more likely that I do that using ssh (this is why I thought about blocking the login).

Comment: Ah, if you have another system you can SSH in from then this doesn't really help.

Comment: Yes, but that is unlikely. I do that only if I have to fix something urgent. The idea is good nonetheless.

Comment: `rmmod: ERROR: Module usbhid is builtin.` darn!

Comment: Ah that's a shame, you should still be able to detach the devices — let's see...

Comment: This answer is the most helpful in my case, as it is the only one I did not consider earlier and the one I learned most from. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a two-pronged attack:

1. Set up a script (via root's crontab) that will shutdown (suspend) the computer at 2300 hours.  Set it up to run every minute from 2300 to 2315, just in case something cancels the first one.  This will kick you out come bedtime.
2. Set in your `~/.bashrc`, and in root's as well, a command to halt the system if the time is between 2300 and 0700 hours.  This will prevent login during those times.

---

However, as I mentioned in comments, *nothing* you can set up will be foolproof.  You have root access to your own box.

This is a classic example of looking for a technical solution to a human problem; if you want to sleep between 2300 and 0700 hours, you will need to handle your self-discipline on this point in other ways.  Root can't do that for you, because you *are* root.  It *will* take personal responsibility.

I have plenty of highly workable information on this point, but I will withhold it as it would be off-topic.  :)

Comment: The problem with `.bashrc` is that it is associated with logins, and not with recovers from suspends, but the idea of halting the system as soon as it is turned on is good. About the off-topic, I am interested: if you want to give me some hints, on my website there is a form to send me messages :)

Comment: @AkiRoss, done.  :)  I included my email address as well in case you'd like to respond.  (Commenting here just from general distrust of webform reliability. ;) )

Comment: Received. Unless your IP is russian or chinese, the form should not filter. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the best solution and for the comment of trying to solve a human problem with a technical workaround.

Answer (score 1):

stop gdm and getty for those hours.

Comment: Stopping GDM will terminate my current graphical session, right? What if I want to suspend the session and just not being able to login for some hours?

Comment: Suspending is also a solution.

Comment: Can you articulate, please? I already said I suspend using crontab.

Comment: I mean suspend the process, not the computer.  `kill -SIGSTOP <pid>` then restore with `kill -SIGCONT <pid>`

Comment: That's a really interesting one! I'll try, thanks!

Comment: Discussing with someone from #gdm, it emerged that suspending it may have unhappy side-effects, therefore it is not a recommended solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hahaha, that sounds fun.

You can add a small script in your .bashrc (probably root too) to exit the shell during those hours. This prevents you to open a terminal and change your crontab during that one minute window.

Or you could edit your `/etc/init.d/gdm` and add an `if` clause preventing the daemon to start during those hours.

Comment: Nice, but I think it does not work if you have a session already open, right?

Comment: True, it was intended to prevent you to change crontab file during that one minute window you mentioned.

Comment: Right, but would work only when shutting down the system; actually most of the times I prefer to suspend, so that my session is kept ready and safe for the next day (usually I shut down the system only at very late hours in the night, because I am too lazy to open everything again :D)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a service, lets say `self_discipline`, creating a service varies depending on the system [but there are plenty of online guides](https://blog.frd.mn/how-to-set-up-proper-startstop-services-ubuntu-debian-mac-windows/).

And a sample script that service could start would be something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]
do
   HOUR="$(date +%H)"
   if [ "$HOUR" -gt 23 ] || [ "$HOUR" -lt 07 ]
   then
      shutdown -h now
   fi
   sleep 60                                                                                
done
```

Then just set this service to run on startup which should prevent you being able to disable it by simply rebooting it. If you want to turn it off ahead of time you can just `service self_discipline stop`

Comment: Thanks! I thought about a service as well. In particular, since I am not completely satisfied with PAM, I will probably create a service that ensures the computer is unusable during the night (e.g. trying to suspend the system every few seconds). The only issue with a service is that it is way too easy to stop :D

Comment: @AkiRoss If you set it up to run on start up it should stop you before you have a chance to get to a prompt.

Comment: Yes yes, but I was talking about `service self_discipline stop`, just one line is so easy to type :D EDIT I will try to use two services that are mutually ensuring that the other is running.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Linux to log out at 11pm. Use [LetterMeLater.com](http://www.lettermelater.com/) and set it to email you your login at 7 am (don't make it memorable and make sure that you are not the default email; someone you know that isn't computer savvy so it would be a pain to go through the forgot login).

Enter it from your phone and delete it when you have. Good for steam and game saves if you can't exercise great control with games too.

Also make sure that the email scheduler password is the same as your login. That way you can change it when you want. But only when its emailed to you. This is optional. Maybe you don't want to change it and you know that this will be standard. Test it out until you are happy that it will work for you.